Unable to Transact, Wallet Blocked
My account seems to be blocked, the error message I get each time attempt doing transactions is "this account may not be used to pay transaction fees". This all started after my account was drained after I unknowingly clicked on a malicious link. Any ideas on how I address this problem?

There is no way to block a wallet on Solana. There are scam sides though which may transfer the ownership of your account to a program, which leads to the error message you are seeing.
Without more details its hard to say what happened to your wallet, but there is a tool that helps with recovering some funds in that case since you still have the private key to your wallet you may be able to sign certain transactions using a seperate feepayer.
Here is the tool written by https://twitter.com/HeyAndyS, but use at you own risk: https://twitter.com/sol_recovery
